# Calling the function on every iteration of for loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, async-await, dom-events

```
function myFunction(xml) {
  var i;
  var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  var table =
    "<tr><th>Title</th><th>Author</th><th>Cover Page</th><th>Ratings</th></tr>";
  var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("best_book");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    bookname = x[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    authorname = x[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    table +=
      "<tr><td class='book'>" +
      bookname +
      "</td><td class='author'>" +
      authorname +
      "</td><td>" +
      "<img src='" +
      x[i].getElementsByTagName("image_url")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
      "' height='100px' width='70px'>" +
      "</td><td>" +
      "<div class='stars' data-rating='1'>" +
      "<span class='star'>&nbsp;</span>" +
      "<span class='star'>&nbsp;</span>" +
      "<span class='star'>&nbsp;</span>" +
      "<span class='star'>&nbsp;</span>" +
      "<span class='star'>&nbsp;</span>" +
      "<input type='button' value='Add Rating' onClick = 'submitRating()'>" +
      "</div>" +
      "</td></tr>";
    console.log(bookname);
  }

  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = table;
}
```

```
async function submitRating() {
  try {
    let boo = bookname;
    console.log(boo);
    let auth = authorname;
    console.log(auth);
    let rat = 5;
    console.log(rat);
    let data = JSON.stringify({
      author: auth,
      book: boo,
      rating: rat
    });
    console.log(data);
    let res = await fetch(hostUrl + "api/ratings", {
      method: "POST",
      body: data,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
    });
    console.log(res);
    res.json().then(matter => {
      console.log(matter);
    });
    // let myJson = res.json();
    // console.log(myJson);
    if (res.status == 200) {
      console.log("the status is " + res.status);
    } else {
      console.log("the status is " + res.status);
      alert("rating not given");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error:" + error);
  }
}
```

I am trying to call `submitRating` function on every *iteration* of for loop,
but I am not getting the correct method for this in **JavaScript**. 
Right now, after running the loop, `onclick = submitRating()` function only submitting the last value in mongodb.
Can someone help me with this please?

Comment: You're not calling any function in your for loop, you're generating some HTML containing a button with an onclick event. I think you took the problem from the wrong end. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because the `bookname` and `authorname` retain the last value set by the final iteration of the for loop. In other words, these variables are simply overwritten multiple times until the for loop ends. If you want to store these information on a per-item basis, you can store them in HTML5 `data-` attributes and retrieve them in the onclick handler.

For example, you can do this:

```
"<input type='button' value='Add Rating' data-bookname='"+bookname+"' data-authorname='"+authorname+"' onClick='submitRating(this)' />"
```

And then, in your `submitRating` method, you can simply read the information using [`Element.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset):

```
async function submitRating(el) {
    const bookname = el.dataset.bookname;
    const authorname = el.dataset.authorname;

    // More logic here
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Terry, This solution solved my problem. :)

Comment: @SahilTyagi Glad to help :)